# Spring Web-Flow PDF cutting off long source code text

Tags: spring, pdf, reference, springsource

I found that the spring web flow reference guide PDF is cutting off very long lines of source code. I am not sure if other spring project reference PDFs have this issue. [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/current/spring-webflow-reference/pdf/spring-webflow-reference.pdf) is a link to the PDF with the problem.

Check out pages 7, 8, or 9 near the bottom for an example of the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pdf you could download [spring-webflow-reference in html-format (zipped single-page)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference-single.zip)